# Calculating a ratio in one column based grouped by countries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following question to answer:

Which companies have more than 20% cancelled orders within their warehouse country?

This is the dataset

[image: see it here]

What I'm looking for is a list of companies that have more than 20% of orders being cancelled

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  warehouse_city,
  COUNT(*)         AS total_orders,
  SUM(CASE WHEN arrival_status = 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS cancelled_orders
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  company_name,
  warehouse_city
HAVING
  COUNT(*) < 5 * SUM(CASE WHEN arrival_status = 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```